# How do I get raw VBScript command line arguments?

Tags: vbscript, cmd, command-line-arguments

How do I get the entire command line in a .vbs file?  I'm looking to process it myself, with all special characters/quotes still intact.

For example, the command:

```
cscript.exe example.vbs /month:April /price:500 "Joe Smith" is "our" guy
```

I am NOT interested in:

```
WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("month")
= April

WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
= Joe Smith

Dim StrArgs
For Each arg In WScript.Arguments
  StrArgs = StrArgs & " " & arg
Next
= /month:April /price:500 Joe Smith is our guy
```

These methods mangle and strip all quotes.

I want to get the raw arguments, unprocessed in any way:

> /month:April /price:500 "Joe Smith" is "our" guy

Comment: You can't. I like wishful programming.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31100398/2861476) could be adapted to your needs

Comment: @MCND Actually, yes.  My question looks like an exact duplicate of that, and I can use that answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use WMI:

```
Option Explicit

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

Dim oWMI : Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Dim oCol : Set oCol = oWMI.ExecQuery( _
  "SELECT Commandline FROM Win32_Process", _
  "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
Dim oElm
For Each oElm In oCol
   If Instr(oElm.CommandLine, "40056204.vbs") Then
      WScript.Echo "CommandLine: " & oElm.CommandLine
   End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 40056204.vbs /month:April /price:500 "Joe Smith" is "our"      guy
CommandLine: cscript 40056204.vbs /month:April /price:500 "Joe Smith" is "our"      guy
```

Comment: The only problem I see is that you can have two instances of the same script running.

Comment: @MCND - no, you just put a streamlined version of this code into a library/into each file you need the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the same script in same disk file, with several instances running at the same time but with different arguments.